# Помощь по объединению или удалению аккаунта

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено

Есть два аккаунта на stackoverflow

Первый, действующий: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/308951/maximlensky

Второй, забытый: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/330688/maximlensky

Со второго аккаунта я забыл способ авторизации ...с первой учётки регался через goolge письмо получил а вот от второй я не помню каким образом я регистрировался

Можно ли объединить эти учётки или удалить вторую ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учетные записи объединены. Спасибо! =)